# My Python Turtle Window Will Open But Not Show Any Drawing

Tags: python, python-turtle

In my python turtle code, my turtle window opens but shows no drawing.

Here is my code:

```
import turtle
turtle.mainloop()

tim = turtle.Turtle()
tim.color('red')
tim.pensize(5)
tim.shape('turtle')

tim.forward(15)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `turtle.mainloop()` has to be at the end of the code. Otherwise the turtle window gets opened but the rest of the code will never be reached after that.

```
import turtle
    
tim = turtle.Turtle()
tim.color('red')
tim.pensize(5)
tim.shape('turtle')

tim.forward(15)
turtle.mainloop()
```